# mixed language indexing in solr

Tags: solr, nlp

I am indexing mixed-language pdf documents to solr, meaning one single document is made out of different languages, mainly english parts and french parts. I would like to stream each part to a specific field depending on the language.

So, lets say "Hello, my name is nicolas. Je voudrais extraire du texte avec solr" would be indexed into two fields, 
Field_en "Hello my name is nicolas"
 and Field_fr "Je voudrais extraire du texte avec SOLR".

Currently, I am only able to do so at the document level (using LangDetect processor from solr), but it doesn't help for mixed language documents.

If it is too difficult, I would at least like to be able to selectively remove one language during indexing, and get one single language in a field.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no built-in support in Solr to do what you want, so my suggestion would be to use the handler's support for only extracting the content (and not indexing it) by appending `extractOnly` to the request. That will give you the content of the document back.

You can then parse the content and run each sentence through a classifier for language - or if you want to keep it inside Solr - have a document for each sentence. Depending on the number of documents and what you're going to query for, that might not be viable though.

Comment: I have approx 300 pdf document with 10 pages. Having a document for each sentence might be an option, providing I can then rebuilt the whole document, which loos a bit tricky to me.

Comment: You can have a separate core with the complete document and retrieve it after a match has been found in a sentence (which has a reference to the document id). search and retrieval does not need to be against the same collection / structure. You can also use the first collection to get ids to perform faceting or other operations against and filter on those ids in the second collection. Given the number of documents a solution with a document pr. sentence (pr. the smallest unit that can change language, really) could work.

Comment: ok, I will consider this proposition. For the moment I decided to run the cleaning using another tool (R) as a "patch solution". Thanks !